# Gradle sync failed upon updating Android Studio version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I recently was instructed by Android Studio to update to the new version (3.0.1, from 2.3.3). After several hours of fixing problems (Why must it be so hard to correctly update this piece of software?) I am now stuck.

I am getting this error on a project that previously worked perfectly:

```
Gradle sync failed: com.google.appengine.gradle.model.AppEngineModel PluginClassLoader[com.google.gct, 0.2.8]com.google.appengine.gradle.model.AppEngineModel PluginClassLoader[com.google.gct, 0.2.8]
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (6s 343ms)
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Edit: After adding google() in repositories in build.gradle and changing gradle versions in gradle-wrapper.properties I now have a slightly shorter error message:

```
Gradle sync failed: com/google/appengine/gradle/model/AppEngineModelcom/google/appengine/gradle/model/AppEngineModel
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (236ms)
```

Edit 2: Now I was able to get a slightly different error message:

```
Error:(5, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'TestApp2'.
Plugin with id 'appengine' not found.
```

Googling this gives no sensible results either. But this sounds like a simple poblem to solve? Is there some SDK tool that I must add? And which one?

Edit 3: Here is the build script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Edit 4: A different error I was able to generate. I get different errors when rebuilding the project.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'TestApp2'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find jsr305.jar (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9).
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
   > Could not find commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6).
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
```

Edit 5: I now uploaded the long log file to https://ufile.io/4qc3s.
I am very thankful for any suggestions on how I should go about to find a way to solve this problem.

Edit 6: I have now discovered that I am unable to open project structure.

Comment: Have you read and tried this article? Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle

Comment: share your build.gradle file

Comment: I have now provided build.gradle.

Comment: also you want to change your gradle-wrapper.properties file with this line

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: Thank you, but I have already tried that, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that downloading and reinstalling the latest version of Android Studio was the solution. I didn't do this before because there are many answers on this site advising against this.